# Footer doesnt work

Tags: html, css

first the code:

CSS:

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
body,html{
    height:100%;
 
}
body{
background:url('../images/bg.png');
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
#wrapper{
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top:120px;
    position:relative;
}
.newscard a{

 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
 font-family:bebas;

}

#p1{
padding:10px;
font-family:bebas;

}
.textfeed{
font-family:Arial;
font-size:17px;
}
.newsfeed h1{

 text-align:center;
 font-family:bebas;
 font-size:35px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 color:white;
}
.newslink{
margin-top:30px;
text-align:center;

}
.newslink p{
background:blue;
padding:10px;

}
.newscard{

 margin-left:50px;
 
 display:inline;

 padding:20px;
 border-radius:5px;
 
}
.newsfeed{
 margin-top:50px;
 margin-bottom:50px;
 width:89%;
 padding:50px;
 background:rgba(81, 162, 224, 0.4);

}


.wrap {
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 10px;
}
.box {
 margin-top:40px;
 background:rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.8);
 margin-right:20px;
 color:white;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   width: 30%;
   border-radius:5px;
}
.text{
font-family:Arial;
padding:10px;
}
.titlen{
font-family:bebas;
text-align:center;
margin-bottom:20px;
font-size:20px;
}


.footer{
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:200px;
 background: #32658d;
 text-align:center;
 bottom:0;
 z-index:1;
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 float:left;

}
.footer .ul{

 padding:10px;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin-left:200px;
}
.footer .ul li{
 
 padding:5px;
 list-style-type:none;
 display:inline;


}
.footer .ul li a{
 font-family: bebas;

 font-size:18px;
 
 padding:0px 25px;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;

}

.footer .ul li a:hover{
 
 color:#404040;
 font-weight:bold;
}

HTML:
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

 <div class="dia">
  <img src="images/eslone.jpg"/>
  <span id="span1">WIR HABEN UNS FUER DIE ESL ONE COLOGNE 2016 QUALIFIZIERT</span>
  <span id="span2">WE DID IT!</span>
 </div>
 
 <div class="sponsors">
  <img src="images/ibp.png" width="100px"/>
  <img src="images/hyper.png" width="180px"/>
  <img src="images/eizo.png" width="180px"/>
 </div>
 
 <div class="newsfeed">
 <h1>News</h1>
  <div class="wrap">
  <?php 
   $abfrage = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6";
   $result = mysql_query($abfrage);
   
   
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   
  ?>
  <div class="newscard">
   <?php
     $title = $row[1];
     $text = $row[2];
     $autor = $row[3];
     $date = $row[4];
     $thumb = $row[5];
     $phpdate = strtotime( $date );
     $date = date( 'd.m.Y', $phpdate );
     if(strlen($text) > 200){
      $text = substr($text,0,200)."...</br></br><a href='news.php' ><p align='center'>Weiter<img src='images/Next.png' width='15'/></p></a>";
     }else{
     
     }
     echo "<div class='box'>
          <div class='thumbnail'>
        <img src='".$thumb."' width='234px' style='border-radius:5px'/>
          </div>
          
         <div class='text'>
        <div class='titlen'>
         ".$title."
        </div>
        ".$text."
         </div>
         <div class='nff'>
         
        <p id='p1'>".$autor." &nbsp;- &nbsp;".$date."</p>

         </Div>
      </div>
      
      
     ";
     
    }

    
   ?>
  </div>

  
 </Div>
 </Div>
 
</Div>

<?php include('footer.php');?>
```

Now i have an issue with the footer. If i add a footer outside the wrapper , it will appear inside the newsfeed. And it isnt the full screen width, although i add width:100%. The footer.php only contains the div with a text. How can i fix the footer that it is always on the bottom. Not fixed but always under the newsfeed and not in the newsfeed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:absolute;` and `float:left;` from the CSS footer selector.  Those properties are breaking it out of the regular document flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a footer-tag in your php file instead of a normal div.